# Java : Read data from txt to String[][]

Tags: java, string, file, split

My problem, I have a txt file which look like this :

```
CA-ADAPT-BAT18AH;CABLE ADAPTATION POUR CHARGER BATTERIE 18Ah

OP-CBL-PX738;CABLE TM 220V BUL 738 4.5M

OP-PAN-CABLE-Y;CABLE Y POUR PIV MINI & MAXI (1 FEM - 2 MAL)

OP-PAN-DATA;Câble datacom

OP-TMSSA-DATA;Câble datacom

OP-SOL-CABLE-1;CABLE POUR PANNEAU SOLAIRE : BOITIER VERS PIV
```

There is 2 information's per line, separated by an ";"

In my code java I have a var like "String[][] info = new String[25][2];"

I just want to read the whole file an put the 1st information of the 1st line in info[0][0] and the 2nd information of the 1st line in info[0][1]. 
And do the same process for the rest of the data of the file.

So here is my code :

```
public class Function {

public static String[][] getCable() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String delim = ";";
    String line = null;
    String[][] info = new String[25][2];
    String[] temp; 
    int i = 0,j = 0,a = 0,b = 0;

    String filePath = "C:/Users/ogh/Desktop/Appli Java/cable.txt";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath));

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            if (j == 0) info[i][j] = "ID : "; 
            if (j == 1) info[i][j] = "Descr. : ";
        }
        j = 0;
    }

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        line = scanner.nextLine(); // get 1 line
        temp = line.split(delim); // split that line in 2 with ";"
        info[b][a] = info[b][a] + temp[a]; 
        info[b][a+1] = info[b][a+1] + temp[a+1];

        if (a >= 1) {
            a = 0;
            b++;
        }
    }

    scanner.close();    

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        System.out.println(i+ "-> Info :"+ info[i][0]+"\t"+info[i][1]);
    }

    return info;
}

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
        getCable();
    }
 }
```

And the output I get : All the Id are in the info[0][0] and all the description are in the info[0][1]

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any `a++` in your code.

Comment: learn to use a debugger.  Most IDE should have already bundled one and such problem is super easy to spot by yourself using debugger by looking at the change of variables when stepping through your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not incrementing `b`. Your statement

```
if (a >= 1) {
    a = 0;
    b++;
}
```

will never be executed, because `a` is never >=1. You don't even need that if statement. Just replace it with `b++` to go to the next row for each iteration of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

just do this

```
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine(); // get 1 line
            info[a]= line.split(delim); 
            a++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
temp[a]=String.split(";");
a++;
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        if (j == 0) info[i][j] = temp[0]; 
        if (j == 1) info[i][j] = temp[1];
    }
    j = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would read the lines to a List first

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("1.txt"),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and then transform lines into array

```
String[][] a = new String[lines.size()][];
for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    a[i] = lines.get(i).split(";");
}
```